# json Parsing trouble in android

Tags: android, json

I get a problem when I parse this text as JSON. First, I created `jsonobject` from an URL. I can't show data when debugging, can anyone help me?

**JSON:**

```
[

    {
        "Tarih":"21.12.2015",
        "Imsak":"05:51",
        "Gunes":"07:22",
        "Ogle":"12:18",
        "Ikindi":"14:39",
        "Aksam":"17:02",
        "Yatsi":"18:26",
        "Kible":"09:41"
    }

]
```

I tried this code to solve it, but the JSON wasn't correctly parsed:

**Java Code:**

```
jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://namazvakitleri.ahmeti.net/index.php?islem=getSehirList&ulke_id=2");

try {
    // Locate the NodeList name
    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("d");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
        jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
        WorldPopulation worldpop = new WorldPopulation();
        worldpop.setCountry(jsonobject.optString("SehirId"));
        worldpop.setPopulation(jsonobject.optString("population"));
        world.add(worldpop);

        // Populate spinner with country names
        worldlist.add(jsonobject.optString("SehirAdi"));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: post your complete json, what is mean by  getJSONArray("d"); in your code

Comment: your response is `JsonArray` not `JsonObject`

Comment: @Diego: u r getting wrong Json response. Response shd be within { and }.

Comment: post your getJSONfromURL method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'[' indicates a JsonArray whereas '{' indicates a JsonObject. You have assigned the result to the JsonObject. Instead of that assign it to JsonArray.

Also I don't see any key as "d" in you response.

Try this :

```
jsonarray = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("http://namazvakitleri.ahmeti.net/index.php?islem=getSehirList&ulke_id=2");
try {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    WorldPopulation worldpop = new WorldPopulation();


                    worldpop.setCountry(jsonobject.optString("SehirId"));
                    worldpop.setPopulation(jsonobject.optString("population"));
                    world.add(worldpop);

                    // Populate spinner with country names
                    worldlist.add(jsonobject.optString("SehirAdi"));

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

But again please note your response does not contain this keys 'SehirId', 'population' and 'SehirAdi'

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work.. jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("http://namazvakitleri.ahmeti.net/index.php?islem=getSehirList&ulke_id=2");

Comment: I got a error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from JSONObject to JSONArray

Comment: it means you are getting jsonobject as response from the 'JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL()' method. But you have posted a Json which is array..can you again verify and post the json response that you get.

Comment: when I tried to parse your url request. I got this as a response. is this the response that you are expecting? : [{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"SehirAdi":"ADANA","SehirId":"500"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"SehirAdi":"ADIYAMAN","SehirId":"501"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"SehirAdi":"AFYON","SehirId":"502"}]

Comment: glad to hear that. happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Your response is `JsonArray` not a `JsonObject`.

Now you have two ways to solve this problem.

1. change your `getJSONfromURL()` to return `JsonArray`
2. change response from server to return `JsonObject` instead of `JsonArray`

after doing above changes you must need to parse it according to your response.

**Note** : You have catch block available, so please try to check error in logcat and search on google related to that error.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution :

```
 try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("Your Response");

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(0);

        Iterator keyNames = jsonObject.keys();

        while (keyNames.hasNext()) {

            String keyName = (String) keyNames.next();

            String keyValue = jsonObject.getString(keyName);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```